Updating to react native 0.73 , UI is freezing and becomes unresponsive with react-native-maps in use
I have updated an app to latest react native 0.73.x , Production app UI on iOS starts to freeze and becomes unresponsive , I load react-native-maps with lots of markers as the main screen , There was no performance issues before the update, any idea ?

Managed to resolve the issue, by refactoring the map setup/code, I had to make sure the map markers only renders once, cleaned up the states connected and ignored any external state update that shouldn't update the markers, like region update, by dispatching the new region over redux and reading the state where ever its needed only, preventing markers from re-rendering each region update(user drag actions).
So RN 0.73 has nothing to do with the issue.
